# Is there any version of Ubuntu not in Simplified Chinese, but in Traditional Chinese?

Tags: language-support

I am from Hong Kong and we use only Traditional Chinese.  In Hong Kong SAR, people do not usually use Simplified Chinese. Is there a version of Ubuntu that provides Traditional Chinese?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has Traditional Chinese version.

Going through System Setting -> Language Support

1. Download Traditional Chinese language support.  You can do this in the "Install / Remove Languages" section.  Your computer should be able to display Chinese Characters now (maybe after reboot).  You may also want to install language support of other languages.
2. (Optional) Drag your language, 漢語 (香港), to the top, so that your applications would use Traditional Chinese if it's available.